# Excel - Multiple formula required to use values on sheet to find those values in a list to then create a range and count certain critera

Tags: excel

So, I have two "dates" on one sheet that I want to then locate on another sheet (which is a large list of dates with whether they are working days), create a range and count both the total days and the total working days (NOT including the first date).

I have read a number of forums trying to use ADDRESS or INDEX to locate the cells but I am not sure then how to incorporate a cell location into a new formula

In the example, I would expect the result to show:

20 working days, 28 days in total

I don't know how to attach my excel sheet which would make it a lot easier to figure out I am sure!

Screenshots (basic version)

Cover Sheet with Dates:
[image: Cover Sheet with Dates]

Dates:

[image: Dates]

Comment: Take a screenshot or maybe add some sample data. You might be able to use `COUNTIF` or `COUNTIFS` but hard to say for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use a countifs formula.

something like:

`MinDate` is a single cell: with the smaller date

`MaxDate` is a single cell: the larger date

`Date_List` is a range (I'm assuming column) that covers all the dates in question, doesn't have to be in order

`Date_worked` is another range of cells (i'm assuming in the column next to date list) that is a list of D/X values of weather it was worked or not.

total days within range:

```
=countifs(Date_List,">=" & MinDate, Date_List, "<=" & MaxDate)
```

total working days:

```
=countifs(Date_List,">=" & MinDate, Date_List, "<=" & MaxDate,Date_Worked,"=D")
```

`countifs` will count the number of rows that fit all the criteria.  So it goes down line by line and says:  "is this value of date_list greater than MinDate, while this value of date_list is less than MaxDate, and while this value of date_worked is true; all at the same time?"

if all 3 criteria are true, then it counts the block.

you may also find `sumifs` handy.

hope it helps

Comment: Thansk for your help.  Looking at an alternative, if D3 had a value of "3M" and D31 had a value of "3W", could you apply similar logic to work out the same result? Rather than replying on the dates?

Comment: yes.  you can work the criteria to look for anything really, as long as it can evaluate to true or false.  So a good way would be to replace the last criterion with `"<>X"`  which would count everything that was not X.

Comment: Also, when using excel, Helper columns are helpful.  (pun intended).  In a new column, add something to measure what it is you want to find.  I usually do true/false formulas.  So if you want to search a value for sundays and the days that are marked 3M or 3W.  in the helper column you can use `=or(Weekday="Sunday",Worked="3M",Worked="3W")`  then just point the countif to that column of trues and falses, and have it look for True's.

Comment: Thanks Robert. I will have to pick this up on Monday when back in the office. Will let you know how I get on or if I have any further questions. Appreciate your help